# How can I install tum_simulator on ROS Hydro? The instructions are written for fuerte

Tags: ros, tum-simulator, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I install tum_simulator on ROS Hydro? The instructions are written for fuerte

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193159/how-can-i-install-tum_simulator-on-ros-hydro?-the-instructions-are-written-for-fuerte/) by [Pa El](https://answers.ros.org/users/20112/pa-el/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-09-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[This repository](https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_simulator) seems to contain updated/catkinized `tum_simulator` for *Hydro*.

**Edit**: This worked for me on *Hydro*:

```
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
mkdir -p ~/tum_simulator_ws/src
cd ~/tum_simulator_ws/src
catkin_init_workspace
git clone https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_simulator.git
cd ..
rosdep install --from-paths src -i 
catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash
roslaunch cvg_sim_gazebo ardrone_testworld.launch
```

Not all launch files work though.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2014-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alvar](https://answers.ros.org/users/21018/alvar/) on 2015-02-23**:
I met the following error
fatal error: common/Plugin.hh: No such file or directory
#include "common/Plugin.hh"

**Comment by [mimpho](https://answers.ros.org/users/22438/mimpho/) on 2015-05-20**:
The above procedure does work for me as well, but i can still not view the ar_drone world in my gazebo, it just does not seem to load/download the different models. Any idea what problem is there?
one of the errors is:
Error [ModelDatabase.cc:408] Unable to download model[model://nist_maze_wall_trip